# Is it fine to use Array.prototype.forEach in a loop?

Tags: javascript, foreach, jshint

JSHint is complaining at me because I'm looping over an object using `for(o in ...)`, then using a `o.somearray.forEach(function(){...});` inside. It's saying to not create functions within loops, but does it even matter in this case? It looks a bit nicer since there's less lines and it looks (slightly) better, but are there any major implications from it?

Is it any better to use a normal for-loop and iterate over the array like that, or is it fine to create a function and use the ECMA 5 version?

I'm doing something like this:

```
for(var i in data) {
   data[i].arr.forEach(function(...) {
      // do magic
   });
}
```

Comment: Can you please show the piece of code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is fine to use `forEach`, what it is suggesting here is that the function that you are passing to `forEach` should be created outside of the loop, something like the following:

```
var doMagic = function(...) {
    // do magic
};
for (var i in data) {
    data[i].arr.forEach(doMagic);
}
```

Creating functions within a loop is discouraged because it is inefficient, the JavaScript interpreter will create an instance of the function per loop iteration. Additional details are provided in [JSLint Error Explanations: Don't make functions within a loop](http://jslinterrors.com/dont-make-functions-within-a-loop/).

Comment: Can you provide a benchmark for "inefficient"? While it must be a new function-object, I would be surprised if it was not well-optimized; the entire function body can be shared, for instance, and it won't create any more execution contexts.

Comment: Also http://jsperf.com/shared-vs-per-iteration, not sure what the difference is with your version.

Comment: It does more than my version. My version *only* creates the "new" functions in the *same* execution context, as this question shows.

Comment: I think these other versions of the test also have the same execution context, I think it might come down to how smart the browser is and possibly a difference between named vs unnamed functions.

Comment: They can't/don't have the same execution context. Because a *new* function with a *new* execution context creates the "new" functions. This will be slower (although perhaps not by much) because in this case *new* execution contexts must be created. (Although this argument is less strong vs the first link posted.)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's fine to nest the constructs. It's also fine to create a "new" function each loop. And,

**Performance differences when creating many "new" functions within the *same* execution context is an implementation detail; but it is *not* inherently slower.** (See this [jsperf test case](http://jsperf.com/shared-vs-new-fn)<sup>1</sup>)

Even though a *new* function-object will be created in the "new" case each loop the *same* number of execution contexts are created - namely, the current execution context and when the function is called. Smarter JavaScript implementations can trivially take advantage of this; or they may not.

I prefer the inline-method in this particular case.

---

<sup>1</sup> Test on the *particular* JavaScript implementation of course;

- In IE 10, Chrome 33, and FF 23 show equivalent performance
- FF 27 favors the "new" function case
- Safari 5 buggers the numbers and *runs slower in the "new" case*